# At what point of the evolution an alien civilisation living in earth-like planet may differ?

Tags: evolution, aliens, earth-like

Somewhere in the universe, there is a planet similar to the Earth, with living beings similar to humans:

- they can find on this planet any resources we can find on earth (water, clay, cooper, ...);
- they can do anything a human can do (move, handle objects, ...);
- (edit) they are biologically identical to humans.

I think* that there is a significant chance that this civilization build primitive weapons, hunts or boats, like we did before - just because their life may depend on it. ... and maybe later, they will also discover farming, agriculture, etc.

But I doubt that there is a significant chance that one day they will build an iPhone, because we didn't build this for survival.

That said, it must be a moment from where the alien technology should differ from ours. Which era?

*this is just my supposition and not an assumption, feel free to contradict this if necessary.

Comment: How biologically close are your species to humans? Our bodies' structure, needs and capabilities dictate most of our inventions.

Comment: the statement "they can do anything a human can do (move, handle objects, ...)" is not sufficient?

Comment: Probably at every point, just a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Suppose your species are cold-dwellers - they thrive in near-freezing temperatures, but summer heat is deadly for them. That would change the whole course of their civilization.

Comment: Ok. Feel free to cover several scenarios (or the one of your choice). Responses for a very biological similar alien or very different are both interesting in my opinion.

Comment: @roipoussiere Unfortunately questions on this site need to be specific. If you don't specify you run the risk of your question getting put on hold as too broad.

Comment: @roipoussiere I've been thinking about this a lot recently, and have only held out this long because I couldn't think of a way to write up a narrow enough question for Worldbuilding.SE. 

I always wondered whether evolution has to work the way it does. Rather, does evolution (as we know it) work the way it does because of some quirk in our system of transcription of genetic code, or will any group of organisms become progressively better able to survive their environment, regardless of how they store and replicate their genetic information, regardless of how they breed?

Comment: @roipoussiere Furthermore, I wonder whether our system DNA and genetic information is the only way life can exist? Will alien "life" have something that is recognizably genetic information? Will they have something that looks like DNA, with a few minor changes? Will they have the exact same DNA as us? Given 1000 planets with some form of life, will they all eventually progress to civilization, or will many of them stay the same? How much of this stuff is deterministic and how much is pure chance?

Comment: @roipoussiere unfortunately I agree with sphennings, this question is probably too broad. Worldbuilding.SE is an amazing place but in order to keep it that way it must have bounds. Many questions can be posed such that they are answerable here, but many cannot be. I do wish there was a way to ask this unique community more open-ended questions, though.

Comment: Yes, this is too broad. There is a whole set of related "alternative history" questions which usually go like "Could we have an invention X without inventing Y?", but those are much better defined because they deal with human history. In your case, you need to either specify how your species are different, or assume that they are no different from humans.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question lacks constraints and invites all kinds of speculation. An alien civilisation can diverge from our development path at any arbitrary point. In fact, it may never follow it in the first place. I would suggest editing your question to make it more specific. As it is now I vote to put on hold as opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I edited my question, I hope it's sufficient.

Comment: That is better, but still too broad, because people can (and really did) write  volumes about it. I advise you to research "alternative history" genre (focusing on technology rather than politics) and then further refine your question here.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between Earth and its people and this imaginary Earth-like planet and its human-like people which would start a divergence.